# PHPUnit - Mocked method expects to be called once fails

Tags: php, phpunit

I don't know if it's a normal PHPUnit behaviour, but I encountered an impediment developing tests with mock generators. I need to check if one method was called one time, so I developed a short example:

**ClassA.php**

```
<?php

class ClassA
{
    public function foo()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

**ClassB.php**

```
<?php

require_once "ClassA.php";

class ClassB
{
    /**
    * @var ClassA
    */
    private $objA;

    /**
    * @param ClassA $objA
    */
    public function __construct(ClassA $objA)
    {
        $this->objA = $objA;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        //$this->objA->foo();
    }
}
```

**ClassAMocks.php**

```
<?php

require_once "ClassA.php";

class ClassAMocks extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function getClassAMock()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('ClassA')->getMock();
        $mock->expects($this->exactly(1))->method('foo');
        return $mock;
    }
}
```

**ClassBTest.php**

```
<?php
require_once "ClassA.php";
require_once "ClassB.php";
require_once "ClassAMocks.php";

class ClassBTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testBar()
    {
        $objAMock = new ClassAMocks();
        $objB = new ClassB($objAMock->getClassAMock());
        $objB->bar();
    }
}
```

With this setup, because the ClassA's method foo is not called (it's commented), the test should fail, but this is the result:

```
$ phpunit ClassBTest.php
PHPUnit 4.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.

Time: 31 ms, Memory: 3.00Mb

OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```

Tests passed u__u. Then if I create the mocked class inside the test class:

**ClassBTest.php**

```
<?php
require_once "ClassA.php";
require_once "ClassB.php";

class ClassBTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{ 
    public function testBar()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('ClassA')->getMock();
        $mock->expects($this->exactly(1))->method('foo');

        $objB = new ClassB($mock);

        $objB->bar();
    }
}
```

and reexecute the phpunit:

```
$ phpunit ClassBTest.php
PHPUnit 4.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 29 ms, Memory: 3.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) ClassBTest::testBar
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:foo> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Now it fails as expected. So can't we create mocks outside the test class? I was pulling away all the mocks into separated classes for reuse them, so, if anyone has had this same problem, I will appreciate your help :)

Thank you and have a nice weekend!